# Как вернуть из async объект

Tags: javascript, frontend, async-await, асинхронность, fetch

У меня есть async функция load. Как мне из неё вернуть объект?

```
async load() {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(this.urlRead);
    if (response.status === 200) {
      const quests = await response.json();
      return {quests};
    }
  } catch (e) {
      return e.message;
  }
}

const data = this.load();
```

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы из `async` функции получить `return` не в виде промиса ее тоже нужно вызывать в `async` функции через `await`.

в вашем случае можно все обернуть в самовызывающуюся функцию

```
async load() {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(this.urlRead);
    if (response.status === 200) {
      const quests = await response.json();
      return {quests};
    }
  } catch (e) {
      return e.message;
  }
}

const data = (async () => await this.load())();
```